# how to find what hangs rebooting

Tags: linux, reboot, hangs

During reboot my machine hangs on

```
[ OK ] Removed slice system-postfix.slice
```

I don't know if problem is with postfix (guess not, because of `[ OK ]`), but how to find what is next service (which hangs I suppose)

It's still alive - I can keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and get:

```
[447.012345] systemd-shutdow: 35 output lines suppresed due to ratelimiting
[447.012346] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[447.012347] systemd-journal[175]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
```

Then it freezes for about 90 seconds (suppose DefaultTimeout from system.conf) and then finally reboots. This happens on both systems I've upgraded to Jessie.

Comment: Any remote mounts or other connections?

Comment: also try `systemd-analyze blame`.